# CentOS 7 - how to install dependency using wget in an RPM spec file

Tags: centos, packaging, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to write a spec RPM file to build an RPM package. 
Here is in essence my spec file:

```
[...]
Requires: nodejs java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel log4j 

%define _rpmdir ../
%define _rpmfilename %%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}.%%{ARCH}.rpm
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0

%pre
[Some script]


%post
[Some script]

%preun
[Some script]

%postun
[Some script]

%install
[...]

%files
[...]
```

I've managed to install the package dependencies with the preamble `Requires` expect one that doesn't exist as a `yum package` (tomcat8). I found on the internet that the way to install it on centOS is:

```
wget https://harbottle.gitlab.io/harbottle-main/7/x86_64/00853071-tomcat8/tomcat8-8.5.37-2.el7.harbottle.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh tomcat8-8.5.37-2.el7.harbottle.x86_64.rpm
```

But where should I put it in the spec file? I tried to put it in the `%pre` script, but there is a lock on `rpm` that prevent its use. I tried to put it in the `%install` part, but it didn't seem right. Can you please help me to fix this problem? Is there a way to still put it in the `Requires` preamble?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not the way you should manage those dependencies. You should search for a way to make this rpm available in you repositories. I see multiple options:

1. add the harbottle repository:`yum-config-manager --add-repo https://harbottle.gitlab.io/harbottle-main/7/x86_64/`. Now your `yum` will be able to find the tomcat8 rpm by itself
2. If you want to make sure the package remains available; better copy the tomcat8.rpm inside your own repository besides your other rpms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
> this is not the way you should manage those dependencies.
Are you talking about the way I manage all my dependencies or only the `tomcat8`?
I'm trying the second solution. I've created an `RPMS` directory inside the package workspace and put the tomcat8.rpm there. However, what is the correct way to add the dependency to the spec file?

Comment: I meant that you should not interact with the rpm database in post scrips. `requires: tomcat8` is perfect

Comment: Okay! Right now, i've bypassed the issue in adding the `%build` with the `yum` installation to the spec file: `%build
yum install /home/dblab/dblab-frontend-1.0/RPMS/tomcat8-8.5.37-2.el7.harbottle.x86_64.rpm`. Is it correct this way?

Comment: No. You only need to put the `requires` part in your spec file. Yum will handle the requirements for you

Comment: I'm confused. I've tried to put `requires: tomcat8` in the spec file, but when installing the package, I got this error: `Error: Package: frontend-1.0-849.x86_64 (/frontend-1.0-849.x86_64)
           Requires: tomcat8`

Comment: how do you install the package? You should tell yum where he can find tomcat8 (add the repository); then use `yum` to install your package, not `rpm` since `rpm` cannot automatically install dependencies

Comment: I use yum to install the package: `yum install <package_name>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188063/discussion-between-chris-maes-and-bastian-nanchen).